# JUnit Mock test returns null on using InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am trying to unit test my service class but the mock returns null

```
package com.tgt.store.pricetask.pricetask_service;

import com.tgt.store.pricetask.model.PriceTaskMaster;
import com.tgt.store.pricetask.model.TaskModel;
import com.tgt.store.pricetask.repository.PriceTaskMasterRepository;
import com.tgt.store.pricetask.service.DataMigrationService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DataMigrationServiceTest {

  @Mock
  PriceTaskMasterRepository priceTaskMasterRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  DataMigrationService dataMigrationService;

  @Test
  public void
testPriceTaskMasterService_whenTaskModelPassed_thenSavePriceTaskMaster() {

    TaskModel taskModel = new TaskModel.TaskModelBuilder().setTaskID(1)
            .setDueDate("2017-11-01T11:41:00+0000").setIsAlertable("A").setIsPriority("P").setLocationid("1234")
            .createTaskModel();

    PriceTaskMaster priceTaskMaster = new PriceTaskMaster.PriceTaskMasterBuilder().setId(1L).setTaskStatus("A")
            .setAlertable("A").setPriority("P").setLocationId(1234)
            .setDueDate(LocalDateTime.now()).createPriceTaskMaster();

    when(priceTaskMasterRepository.insertPriceTaskMaster(any(PriceTaskMaster.class))).thenReturn(priceTaskMaster);

    PriceTaskMaster savedPriceTaskMaster = dataMigrationService.savePriceTaskMaster(taskModel);

    assertNotNull(savedPriceTaskMaster);
    assertEquals("A", savedPriceTaskMaster.getTaskStatus());
    assertEquals("P", savedPriceTaskMaster.getPriority());
    assertEquals(1234, savedPriceTaskMaster.getLocationId().intValue());
    assertEquals(123456789, savedPriceTaskMaster.getTcin().longValue());

    verify((priceTaskMasterRepository), times(1)).insertPriceTaskMaster(priceTaskMaster);
  }
}
```

In the above code, when call reaches the service class `priceTaskMasterRepository` is null. I am unable to figure out if I am missing something. I have tried RunWith `SpringRunner` and `MockitoJUnitRunner` but same result. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work with `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`?

Comment: yup.. very much sure

Comment: What happens if you use `mock(PriceTaskMasterRepository.class)` instead?

Comment: still same error

Comment: Why do you think priceTaskMasterRepository is null, when you use the MockitoJUnitRunner?  I'm completely sure it won't be.

Comment: Please specify if `priceTaskMasterRepository` is null in your test or your testing class.

Comment: its null in testing class

Comment: How can you tell?  Are you stepping through this with a debugger?  Are you adding lines with `System.out.println`?  What makes you so sure that priceTaskMasterRepository is null at that point?

Comment: I think it'd be better if you provide a simpler example without annotations. Just two lines in the test method. One in which you mock `priceTaskMasterRepository` using `mock` and then another in which you use that mocked object.

Comment: I am stepping in with a debugger and thats where I can see its null in testing class

Comment: Even with MockitoJUnitRunner in place of SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?  I mean, absolutely it should be null when you use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, because SpringJUnit4ClassRunner doesn't initialise mocks; so this is no mystery.  But are you really sure it's  null when you use MockitoJUnitRunner?  And what about dataMigrationService?  has it been initialised when your test method starts?

Comment: Yes, its null even with MockitoJUnitRunner. Thats what has got me confusing. I expected it to atleast run with MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: In that case, the class that you're running is not the class that  you've shown here.  Can you try cleaning your project and rebuilding it?

Comment: I am not sure how much this will help but the mocked repository uses NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Do you think that needs to add some additional configurations?

Comment: If it's null in your testing class. Can you show your testing class?

Comment: could you give us just the basic definition of DataMigrationService ?

In particular, constructors and (if any) setter of priceTaskMasterRepository

This in order to understand which kind of injection Mockito is trying... (constructor, setter or field...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to initialize the `DataMigrationService` field when using the `@InjectMocks` annotation. That will create an instance of the class under test as well as inject the mock objects into it.

```
@InjectMocks
DataMigrationService dataMigrationService = new DataMigrationService();
```

http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

Comment: Thank You @Srikanth, that was it. I just had to initialize that. You saved me from refactoring my whole code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JUnit to run your tests, then you should have something like this:

```
@Before
public void setup()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

This ensures all your mocks are initialised. This is supposed to be unnecessary when using `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

Comment: Venky mentioned he tried with `MockitoJUnitRunner` and it doesn't work.

Comment: I saw that, so it's puzzling. (And hence my note about _supposed_ to be unnecessary.)

Comment: So OP's problem is something other than this.  I don't know what the problem is - that's why I haven't answered the question yet.